# loading from zip to sdl, code working in x64 but not x86

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl, zlib

The below piece of code works when i compile it as x64 bit and works fine, but gives a heap corruption error on x86. i cant figure out whats wrong with it.

```
unzFile data;
std::string filename;
unz_file_info   info;
Uint8*  buffer;
SDL_RWops* rw = NULL;
Mix_Chunk* effect = NULL;

//load zip file and get filename

unzLocateFile(data, filename.c_str(), NULL))
unzOpenCurrentFile(data);
unzGetCurrentFileInfo(data, &info, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)
buffer = (Uint8*)malloc(info.uncompressed_size);
unzReadCurrentFile(data, buffer, info.uncompressed_size))
rw = SDL_RWFromConstMem(buffer, info.uncompressed_size);
effect = Mix_LoadWAV_RW(rw, 1); // <---Heap corruption here
free(buffer);
```

Its being compiled in VS2012, SDL 2.0, Zlib 1.2.7, Minizip 1.1

Do let me know if anymore information is required.

UPDATE:

So i did a little bit of testing, with dr memory, the same codebase is used for loading pngs and wavs, with the appropriate sdl functions for each. They are Mix_loadWAV_RW and IMG_Load_RW. Apparently, the only time heap corruption happens is on the Mix_loadWAV_RW function, the IMG_Load_RW functions go without a hitch. so I am guessing its more to do with Mix_loadWAV_RW function and whats it doing with the memory in each version than the minizip, SDL, opengl and SDL_IMG sections.

I will try and do a test project isolating only SDL_Mixer and minizip. Can anybody tell me what kind of tests I should be doing, or experienced anything similar.

Comment: I'd look for types in those structures that may have changed size due to compiling as 64-bit.  int vs long, etc.  If the data is written assuming a fixed size and that size changes you've got a problem.

Comment: Maybe your dynamical library is not compiled for x86 properly?

Comment: @ C.R. - I am not really certain, because the heap corruption only happens on one particular wav file, in the debugger you can just continue through it, but the opengl output looks like it was passed through a LSD filter. the corrupted wav itself sounds fine. maybe its overwritting some gl stuff. @Ninja - Yes, i would think that is the case, but minizip and Zlib are supposed to be 64bit compatible too, I think the problem is somewhere in minizip > sdl2 copying of the data. even the 64/32 bit size changes are causing problems, i would not know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved the problem. the problem is with the prebuilt binaries that come with vc-devel packages. I just used the seperate runtime binaries provided and viola!!! no more heap corruption. I guess it has to do with the way the packages are built.

Still having issues with the opengl output in the x86 version. But hey its progress and i will open a new question for that.